# Reference on local false discovery rates

Tags: bayesian, references, false-discovery-rate

I am looking for a reference on local false discovery rates.

I'm familiar with FDR and the Benjamin-Hochberg procedure, but am getting lost when it comes to the Bayesian local false discovery rate stuff. A reference with mathematical details would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efron has a book "Large-Scale Inference:
Empirical Bayes Methods for
Estimation, Testing and Prediction" that turned out be exactly what I was looking for. The assumptions are very clearly laid out.

Some of the contents in http://varianceexplained.org/r/empirical-bayes-book/ where also helpful.

This video discusses local false discovery rates near the end: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PVkfQRUGI4